# TF31002 error in Visual Studio 2008 Business Intelligence Development Studio

Tags: sql-server-2008, tfs, ssms, bids

I'm trying to get my SQL 2008 client tools talking to TFS 2010.

The address http://tfs-server:8080/tfs works fine in VS2010, but both SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio 2008) and BIDS (Business Intelligence Development Studio 2008) both give me this error:

```
TF31002: Unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server: <snip>
Possible reasons for failure include:
    - The Team Foundation Server name, port number or protocol is incorrect.
    - The Team Foundation Server is offline.
    - Password is expired or incorrect.
```

I spent a day following the [4-step](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/04/29/How-to-connect-VS-2003-VS-2005-and-VS-2008-to-TFS-2010.aspx) and [7-step](http://blog.arjanfraaij.com/2010/12/install-guide-for-using-team-foundation.html) installation sequences and tried multiple variants of the TFS server's URL, but no luck.  What would you suggest?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assuming you have correctly installed the prereqs for this scenario, in the following order.
**Note:** Even if Team Explorer 2008 is already installed, step 2 and THEN step 3 must be completed.
ie
1. Install Team Explorer 2008 component (either from TFS 2008 media or MS download)
2. Install Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1 (MS download)
3. Install Team Explorer 2008 forward compatibility patch for TFS 2010 (MS download)

You will need to do the following...
1. Click tools > Connect to Team Foundation Server...
2. In the "Connect to Team Project" dialog, click on the Servers button.
3. In the "Add/Remove Team Foundation Server" dialog, click on the Add.. button.
4. In the "Add Team Foundation Server" dialog, enter the URL
      **http://tfs-server:8080/tfs/ProjectCollectionName**
5. ok, ok, ok
6. you should now be able to connect to Team Projects.

Note the difference with connecting in VS 2010, the dialog to enter the URL seems to require the fully qualified http address, as opposed to just entering the servername.

Comment: You have to install SP1 after you install Team Explorer 2008 even if you had it installed before.

Comment: Ok I thought I was already being super clear about that, however for the sake of the ppl that skim read answers i will edit my answer.

Comment: lol, I guess some ppl struggle with reading instructions. personally if i see an ordered list of "things to install" and i have already installed A, I would assume that I still needed to install B, C, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Try `http://tfs-server:8080/tfs/defaultcollection`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the TFS version you use, it might be necessary to have a compatibility pack installed

TFS2010: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10834

TFS2012: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29983